# Flutter Debug: Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

my problem is this:

I want to connect my app to Firebase. I followed all the steps and did everything according to the instructions. When I tried to debug the app, the following error came up:

[image]

When I enter - flutter run - from the terminal, the following happens:

[image]

In flutter doctor -v the following comes out:

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.4, on macOS 11.2 20D64, locale de)
> • Flutter version 1.20.4 at /Users/danielalakin/development/flutter
> • Framework revision fba99f6cf9 (5 months ago), 2020-09-14 15:32:52 -0700
> • Engine revision d1bc06f032
> • Dart version 2.9.2
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 30.0.2)
> • Android SDK at /Users/danielalakin/Library/Android/sdk
> • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
> • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
> Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
> 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
> • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
> • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
> • CocoaPods version 1.10.1
>
> [!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
> • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
> ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
> ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
> 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
>
> [✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
> • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
> • Flutter extension version 3.19.0
>
> [✓] Connected device (1 available)
> • iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • C0991E0B-425B-46BD-9DEA-674181136D99 • ios •
> com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4 (simulator)

And I have the following versions and paths:

> $ pod --version:
> 1.10.1
>
> $ which pod:
> /usr/local/bin/pod
>
> $ which gem:
> /Users/danielalakin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/gem
>
> $ which ruby:
> /Users/danielalakin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby

Do you know how I can solve this problem?

PS: I work on Visual Studio Code and XCode. I use MacOS Big Sur Version 11.2.

Answer (score 26):

I had this same error a number of times in the past, and once right after I upgraded to Flutter 2.0.1 just now. The solution for me was always to run (as previously suggested):
`sudo gem install cocoapods` **then** restart my IDE. I use Android Studio, but same should apply to VSCode as well.

Comment: The `restart my IDE` part seems to be key to make it work

Comment: I had previously run `brew install cocoapods`, which did not help. But this did! Thanks.

Comment: I have a variation of this bug on my machine. If I use bash and do a 'flutter run' command everything works fine. If I 'run' from inside Android Studio I get the CocoaPods not installed / in invalid state error.

I have no additional parameters in my Run/Debug configuration. Can anybody give me clues on either how to debug this or fix it?

Comment: Someone has collected some possible solutions to this in one place already:
https://fluttercorner.com/cocoapods-not-installed-or-not-in-valid-state/
Take note especially of the possibility of if you have multiple installations of cocoapods (and cocoapods-core), checked by reviewing output of `gem list`, then you'll want to `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` and `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core` followed by `sudo gem install cocoapods` followed by quit and reopen your IDE (VS Code).  That is what worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me, but i had to do `brew install cocoapods`

Comment: @HenryDavidSpellsIII same thing, I can build and run trough Xcode or terminal, but not from Android Studio.

Answer (score 24):

The only command who work for me is this one :

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Comment: This worked for me too. I'm using a new macbook pro m3.

Answer (score 9):

For me none of these was helpful,
The workaround was opening the Android studio using Terminal rather than GUI

> open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app

After that, I can use GUI and there was no problem :)!

you can find more info here:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/4981#issuecomment-751443625

Comment: This worked for me, I have installed CocoaPods with gem for anyone else reading.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I believe my issue was that I had two versions of Andriod Studio installed, so the name of the second Android Studio was incorrect and opening it from the dock had a bad link or something.

Answer (score 7):

Restarting VSCode usually fixes the problem, but make sure to close it completely - Cmd+Q on macOS.

Another thing worth trying is cleaning XCode workspace, this can be done via `flutter clean` command.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:
sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: I've tried this command several times and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

if you use Android Studio try restoring the cache in

```
file -> invalidate cache/restart
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to reinstall cocoa pods but additionally I had to reinstall my Visual Studio Code IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on Android Studio 4.1.3. Updating to Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 3 solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

run this command :

> sudo gem install ffi

if on running `flutter doctor`, it still says cocoapods not installed then run this command

> sudo gem install cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

This answer will help if anyone is still facing the issue.

If your are not an admin user for your machine, there are possibilities were you will get this error, as you will not able to run SUDO command.
If in that case install Cocoapods using

```
gem install cocoapods --user-install
```

And then get the exact location using

```
gem which cocoapods
```

Once after that based on the shell your using, EX: zsh or bash, Please add the path to the respective support file.

In my case I have added the path (export PATH="/Users/yourName/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:$PATH") in .zshrc file.

Answer (score 0):

For MAC:
brew install cocoapods
and then navigate to ios and execute 'pod install'.
Exit VS Code and Open and run flutter run.

Answer (score 0):

Run the commands in that order in terminal.

```
cd /opt/homebrew/bin/

PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin

cd

touch .zshrc

echo export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin >> .zshrc
```

then `brew install cocoapods` Don't forget to restart your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by reinstalling the flutter extension on visual code and restarting the ide.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues with cocoapods, tried installing and uninstalling, ruby and cocoapods nothing worked as the path(executable) was not resolved, this command solved my issue

```bash
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```